# Schur multiplier of GL$(n,\mathbb{R})$ and SL$(n,\mathbb{R})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, lie-groups

I have seen questions([Schur Multiplier of general linear group](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/878154/schur-multiplier-of-general-linear-group)) on this topic but did not get the satisfactory answer. Please if possible give me the answer of this question explicitily.

> What is the Schur multiplier of GL$(n,\mathbb{R})$ and SL$(n,\mathbb{R})$.

What do I think since SL$(n,\mathbb{R})$ is perfect and SL$(n,\mathbb{R})\wedge SL(n,\mathbb{R})\cong SL(n,\mathbb{R})$, therefore Schur multiplier of SL$(n,\mathbb{R})$ is trivial. Please guide me.

Comment: The Schur multiplier has one definition viewing this as abstract group, and one as topological group. For $\mathrm{SL}(n,\mathbf{R})$ topologically the Schur multiplier is infinite cyclic for $n=2$ and cyclic of order $2$ for $n\ge 3$. As abstract group, the Schur multiplier is uncountable... see Milnor's book on K-theory for more information.

Comment: @YCor Thanks for your kind information.